# VS doesn't recognize a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have this code in my view

```
@model IEnumerable<P.Models.A>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Images";
}

<h2>Images</h2>
@int i = 0;
<table> 
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if(i % 3 == 0){

    }
}
</table>
```

VS says to me that `i` `doesnot exist in the current context`

what am i doing wrong please?

I tried to add `@` before `i` but still got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining your variable like this:

```
@{int i = 0;}
```

Also inside the body of the `foreach` loop you probably want to be modifying/incrementing the value of this variable.

Oh and you might consider using a `for` loop instead:

```
<h2>Images</h2>
<table> 
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0) 
        {

        }
    }
</table>
```

But of course the best would be to define a view model instead of writing such loops inside your view.